# scale_fill_manual expands the legend with more variables

Tags: colors, legend

I have this vector with colours that I manually define.

```
energy.colours <- c(
  Wind= "bisque3",
  Sole= "yellow3",
  Electricity=  "aquamarine3",
  Hydrogen= "cadetblue4",
  HydrogenCom=  "springgreen4",
  Methanol=  "goldenrod3",
  CO2 =  "grey50",
  Biometan=  "darkorange3"
  ,Heat = "firebrick4", 
  Water="royalblue3",
  Biometan ="white", 
  Biogas="white",
  Biomass="white",
  System="white",
  Oxygen = "purple"
  )
```

Then I am trying to create a ggplot

```
ggplot( aes(fill=energy, y=value, x=time)) + 
      geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") +
      ggtitle(title) +
      theme_gppr()+
      scale_fill_manual(values=energy.colours)+
      xlab("Hours")+
      geom_hline(yintercept=0, linetype="dashed", color = "black", size=1)+
      ylab("MW")
```

Originally the plot generated was similar to the following graph.
[Origianal Grpah](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCmuG.png)

After one month I runned again the same code and the generated plot is the following.

[After one month](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeZCk.png)

It seems that now the scale_fill_manual started to add more elements to the ggplot legend. But I have not changed anything in my code. Perhaps only ggplot package was updated.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: I would like to suggest that there should be a bug with the newest version of ggplot2 (3.3.5). The problem is solved while using a previous version of 3.3.3

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.